# Mapping another domain with a hosting

Tags: hosting, domain, web-hosting, redirect

I have a domain and hosting. Say www.domainA.com. And I have domainB.com domain. I want to use the hosting space of domainA.com. Can I do something that I create directory with the name domainB on the / root directory of domainA.com. And map my domainB.com with domainB directory.

Like both fetches same result:

www.domainA.com/domainB
www.domainB.com  --> redirects to domainA hosting

Any suggestions on it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more details about what time of hosting this is. Is this shared web hosting, a shared host, a dedicated server, etc...

Comment: I didnt purchased a server. So I think its a shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

there're lots lots of ways doing this.
depends on what's (hosting, server, os) you're on and what exactly you want to.

example, for cpanel you can do this:
http://it.dennyhalim.com/2009/05/cpanel-addon-domains-better-way.html

or on apache/vps just use vhost, etc. etc..

Answer (score 0):

Not much detail to go on here, but why not just create DNS records (A or CNAME) that point both domains to the same web server ip address and add host headers to your web site for both domains?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is certainly possible, and the most cost-effective solution that will work with almost any paid hosting solution you may currently have (no matter how cheap) is often called "Domain Cloaking".  This is where pages are served from a resizable frame the size of the browser window, and is a feature offered for free by most domain registrars.

All other solutions which would be a lot more effective and would not lock your secondary site in a frame would all have additional requirements (e.g. a dedicated ip address and the ability to configure additional host-headers) which would probably increase the cost of your original site to the point that you might as well simply purchase a second hosted website with a budget-friendly provider (e.g. GoDaddy) to serve your second site for less than the cost of a single trip to your favorite caffeinated beverage establishment.